# How to get the configuration in my Custom Annotation Processing whitch was defined in my Maven plugin

Tags: maven, annotations, maven-plugin, annotation-processing, maven-compiler-plugin

My goal is read a parameter's value from costom Maven Plugin
during the processing of `process`, I need this value to determine whether to process annotations.

Here is what i done:

1. customize a maven plugin to configure the parameter of `funProcess`

```
@Mojo(defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE, threadSafe = true,
        requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE)
public class PamirsFunctionMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter
    private Boolean funProcess;

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        //todo
        this.getPluginContext().put("funProcess", funProcess);
    }
}
```

this is my maven-plugin's definition.

```
    <groupId>pro.xxx.pamirs.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>pamirs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

2. Build a project to process annotation `@Fun` which is defined in method. So,I need to define A Annotation Processor through `extends AbstractProcessor`，handle the method corresponding to this `@Fun` annotation in the `process` interface.

Using the value  in my Annotation Processor.

I need the value of `funProcess` which is configured within the pom of business project which relying on this Annotation Processor project, then using the value to determine whether to process annotations In the Annotation Processor project.

3. The test project will rely on annotation processing projects and my maven-plugin.
   This is the POM definition .

```
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>pro.xxx.pamirs.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pro.xxx.pamirs.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>pamirs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <funProcess>false</funProcess>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</dependency>
```

I want to know how to get the value in my Annotation Processor.

Comment: Please give more detailed information (best would be a link to a project which shows how it is configured!)

Comment: I added some information，But I don't know if it's described clearly. Thank you very much！